# Como fazer o update para alterar uma linha específica de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, html5, banco-de-dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço o alterar nessa tabela? Sou iniciante no PHP/MYSQL e estou com dúvida como vou fazer esse alterar.
Assim que a pessoa clicar no Ícone de "alterar", ela deve ser encaminhada para uma página, que deve puxar o id da  linha específica clicada na tabela. E essa é a página onde será feita as alterações dos dados.

Mas a questão é que são 2 tabelas diferentes.
Tem 4 tabelas. A de Erros, Clientes, Funcionários e da VIEW.

Preciso da junção da  tabela erros com clientes, para na hora de fazer as alterações, caso eu queira alterar o nome de um cliente específico ou um erro por ex, ele mude os dados sem problemas. Mesmo de tabelas diferentes.

Segue o Codigo.

Script do banco:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb;

USE mydb;

CREATE TABLE clientes (
  cod_clientes INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome_cliente VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  cnpj VARCHAR (14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_clientes)
) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE funcionarios (
  cod_funcionarios INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome_funcionario VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
  login VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  senha VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_funcionarios)
  ) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE erros(
  cod_erros INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tipo_erro VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  solucao TEXT NOT NULL,
  data_ocorrencia DATE,
  sistema VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  Fk_Funcionarios INT UNSIGNED,
  Fk_Clientes INT UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_erros),
  FOREIGN KEY (Fk_Funcionarios) REFERENCES funcionarios (cod_funcionarios) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (Fk_Clientes) REFERENCES clientes (cod_clientes) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ) ENGINE = innodb;
```

Script da VIEW:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS VIEW_LISTA_ERROS;

CREATE VIEW VIEW_LISTA_ERROS AS
SELECT clientes.nome_cliente AS Cliente, erros.cod_erros AS ID, erros.tipo_erro AS Erro, erros.solucao AS Solução, erros.data_ocorrencia AS Data, erros.sistema AS Sistema, funcionarios.email AS Email_do_Funcionario
FROM clientes, erros, funcionarios
where erros.Fk_Clientes = clientes.cod_clientes and erros.Fk_Funcionarios = funcionarios.cod_funcionarios
group by cod_erros, Fk_Clientes, Fk_Funcionarios;

select *from VIEW_LISTA_ERROS;
```

Página de registro de erros e clientes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Script onde faço o Insert:

```
 //Caso não ocorra nenhum erro, permita que os dados sejam inseridos no banco.
  if ($row == 0) {
    $link = conexao();

    $query = "insert into clientes(nome_cliente, cnpj)
    values('{$nome_cliente}', '{$cnpj}')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    //Recupero o id do cliente que acabou de ser inserido
    $idCliente = mysqli_insert_id($link);

      //Recupero o id do funcionaio que está logado na sessão
    $idFuncionario = $_SESSION["id_usuario"];

    $query2 = "insert into erros(tipo_erro,solucao,data_ocorrencia,sistema, Fk_Funcionarios, Fk_Clientes)
    values('{$nome_erro}', '{$solucao}', '{$data}', '{$sistema}', '{$idFuncionario}', '{$idCliente}')";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2);

  header('location: paginaConsulta.php');
  }
```

A parte onde eu puxo a Vieww criada para listar os dados específicos na tabela:

```
         <?php
            $link = conexao();
            $query = $link->prepare('select Cliente, Erro, Solução, Data, Sistema from VIEW_LISTA_ERROS');
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($cliente, $erro, $solucao, $data, $sistema);

            echo "
            <!--Cabeçalho-->
            <div class='row header'>
                <div class='cell'>
                CLIENTE
                </div>
                <div class='cell'>
                ERRO
                </div>
                <div class='cell'>
                SOLUÇÃO
                </div>
                <div class='cell'>
                DATA
                </div>
                <div class='cell'>
                SISTEMA
                </div>
                <div class='cell'>
                <i class='fas fa-tools'></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            ";

            while ($query->fetch()) {
                echo "
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='cell cell2' data-title='Clientes'>
                        $cliente
                    </div>
                    <div class='cell cell2' data-title='Erro'>
                        $erro
                    </div>";

                   echo "
                     <div class='cell cell2' data-title=Solução style='vertical-align:middle; text-align: justify;'> ";
                        echo nl2br("$solucao");
                    echo "</div>";

                    echo"
                    <div class='cell cell2' data-title='Data'>";
                        $data = formatarData($data);
                    echo "$data";   
                    echo"
                    </div>
                    <div class='cell cell2' data-title='Sistema'>
                        $sistema 
                    </div>
                    <div class='cell cell2' data-title='Sistema'>
                        <a href=''><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ";
            }
            echo "  
            <!--Final Conteúdo-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

";

Alguém pode me auxiliar por favor!? Me dá uma dica ou uma lógica.. Como eu posso solucionar isso??

Comment: Você pode localizar o usuário via cod_clientes e dar um UPDATE nele

Comment: Alguém pode me ensinar a fazer o update nesse caso??

Comment: dx já resolvi o problema